# HtmlTextWriter does not render

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmltextwriter

I am using the HtmlTextWriter to create some HTML for me. I want to test if my page actually works but it doesnt render the div.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

```
public partial class web_content_notes_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Configuration Start */
        string thumb_directory = "img/thumbs";
        string orig_directory = "img/original";
        int stage_width = 600;
        int stage_height = 480;
        Random random = new Random();

        // array of allowed file type extensions
        string[] allowed_types = { "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "xls" };

        /* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(thumb_directory))
        {
            string title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            if (allowed_types.Equals(Path.GetExtension(file)) == true)
            {
                int left = random.Next(0, stage_width);
                int top = random.Next(0, 400);
                int rotation = random.Next(-40, -40);

                if ((top > stage_height - 130) && (left > stage_width - 230))
                {
                    top -= 120 + 130;
                    left -= 230;
                }


            }

            //display the files in the directory in a label for testing
            Label1.Text = (file);

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            // Put HtmlTextWriter in using block because it needs to call Dispose.
            using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))

                // The important part:
                writer.Write("<div>testing123</div>");

        }

    }
}
```

I want to add the various variables into the div.

How do i do this? I remember in classic asp/vbscript you had to wrap the code in `<% code %>` not sure if this is the case in ASP.NET / C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to test if my page actually works but it doesnt render the div.

Well no, it wouldn't. Look at what you're doing:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    writer.Write("<div>testing123</div>");
```

So, you're writing to a `StringWriter`. You're then doing *nothing* with that string writer: the text is in memory, and you're letting it get garbage collected, basically.

If you want to write to the `Page`'s response, you'd have to write the result to `Page.Response`. But you should decide whether you want control the *whole* of the response for the request - in which case `Page` probably isn't terribly appropriate - or just a single control, in which case you should probably be putting your code *in a custom control*.

Comment: @sp-1986: Well you have code that's not *useful*. See my edit.

Comment: Jon I see you are an author. I also see that your book has great 5* reviews.

Comment: I could use a hidden form control and then get the stringWriter to output to that on the page.

Comment: @sp-1986: Why would you want to use a *hidden* form control? I think you just want a custom control. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f(v=vs.85).aspx for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet performance wise what is best way to generate and store complex html dynamically stringbuilder or stringwriter?.